# List names of all packages starting with a specific word

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

Say I want to install all the `ubuntu-wallpapers` packages, so I would enter the following at the terminal:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-wallpapers*
```

I am trying to get the same effect using

```
dpkg --set-selections < ./pkgs.txt
```

The problem is, this method does not support the `*` wildcard in the  `pkgs.txt` file.

i was able to get the exact list of packages using

```
apt-cache search ^ubuntu-wallpapers
```

but I get the descriptions too. Is there a way to get only the package names so I can redirect the output to the `pkgs.txt` file?

Comment: General advice: always quote patterns with e.g. asterisks or other special symbols. In your case, the shell will try to interpret `ubuntu-wallpapers*` as a glob, matching files in the current directory. It only works if you have no matching files in the current location, because then the glob will be preserved literally. The safe way to use it is `sudo apt install 'ubuntu-wallpapers*'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache pkgnames` to list only the names of all packages starting with a specific prefix:

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames ubuntu-wallpaper
ubuntu-wallpapers-karmic
ubuntu-wallpapers-vivid
ubuntu-wallpapers-maverick
ubuntu-wallpapers-utopic
ubuntu-wallpapers-wily
ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal
ubuntu-wallpapers-raring
ubuntu-wallpapers-precise
ubuntu-wallpapers-lucid
ubuntu-wallpapers-natty
ubuntu-wallpapers
ubuntu-wallpapers-trusty
ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric
ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy
ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial
```

See `man apt-cache` for more info.

Alternatively, you could process the output of `apt-cache search` and display only the first column by piping it e.g. through one of these commands below or anything similar:

- ```
  cut -d' ' -f1
  ```
- ```
  grep -Eo '^\S+'
  ```
- ```
  sed 's/\s.*//'
  ```
- ```
  awk '{print $1}'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using `apt list` and `egrep` (or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)):

- Search for a group of packages:

  ```sh
  apt list --installed | grep -o "^[^/]*" | egrep "^(gcc|make|git)$"
  ```
- To search for a group of packages *starting with* just remove the `$`:

  ```sh
  apt list --installed | grep -o "^[^/]*" | egrep "^(gc|mak)"
  ```

The command in the middle is to get just the package name. This is equivalent to `cut -f1 -d"/"`.

If given a list of packages you want to know which ones you don't have already installed:

```sh
pkglist="libcurl4-openssl-dev libsdl2-dev libopenal-dev libvulkan-dev libgl1-mesa-dev clang gcc make git"

comm -13 <(apt list --installed | cut -f1 -d"/" | sort) <(echo $pkglist | tr " " "\n" | sort)
```

For the first parameter, you can replace with `apt-mark showmanual` to compare to the **manually** installed packages.

Beware:

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.